# Optimize .Net sequential code

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring

I have the following code that is a set of istruction repeated 20 times:

```
WebBrowserJobs wb1 = new WebBrowserJobs();
Uri uri1 = new Uri("https://www.site1.it");            
wb1.Url = uri1;
wb1.DocumentCompleted+= new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser_DocumentCompleted);

WebBrowserJobs wb2 = new WebBrowserJobs();
Uri uri2 = new Uri("https://www.site2.it");            
wb2.Url = uri2;
wb2.DocumentCompleted+= new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser_DocumentCompleted);

...................
...................
...................

WebBrowserJobs wb20 = new WebBrowserJobs();
Uri uri20 = new Uri("https://www.site20.it");            
wb20.Url = uri20;
wb20.DocumentCompleted+= new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser_DocumentCompleted);
```

The code works properly but each time I have to add a new site to scrap, I have to edit the code...

I wan't to know if it possible ( and how ) to create a kind of iteration based on a simple list of strings that containt the list of urls.

May be Refactoring libraries can be usefull for this work?

Thanks

Comment: This is, er, kinda basic programming. Put the code in a method and call it repeatedly, what is it that is confusing you here?

Comment: The control mechanism you're looking for is called a "loop".  You should *really* start with some introductory tutorials on C#.  Loops will be covered by any of them.

Answer (score 4):

```
var mySites = new []{"http://site1.com", "http://site2.com"};
foreach(var site in mySites) 
{
    WebBrowserJobs wb = new WebBrowserJobs { Url = new Uri(site) };
    wb.DocumentCompleted+= new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser_DocumentCompleted);
}
```

This should work.

Comment: This is assuming that `wb` going out of scope doesn't cause any problems.

Comment: Thanks, I try and let you know

Answer (score 1):

If you need to ensure that your `WebBrowserJobs` objects stay in scope and don't get garbage collected/disposed, then you could do something as simple as this. First a method to set up your job:

```
public WebBrowserJobs CreateBroswerJob(string url)
{
    var wb = new WebBrowserJobs();
    wb.Url = new Uri(url);
    wb.DocumentCompleted += 
        new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser_DocumentCompleted);

    return wb;
}
```

And you call it like this:

```
//Your list of sites, add to this when necessary
var urls = new List<string> 
{
    "https://www.site1.it", 
    "https://www.site2.it", 
    "https://www.site3.it" 
}

var jobs = new List<WebBrowserJobs>();

foreach (var url in urls)
{
    jobs.Add(CreateBroswerJob(url));
}
```

Now you have a collection of job object you can query or loop round and do something with if needed.

Bonus: You can simplify the `foreach` a little with some Linq:

```
var jobs = urls
    .Select(url => CreateBroswerJob(url))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score -3):

have you tried?

```
        foreach (var str in collection)
        {
            WebBrowserJobs wb1 = new WebBrowserJobs();
            Uri uri1 = new Uri(str);
            wb1.Url = uri1;
            wb1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser_DocumentCompleted);
        }
```

Comment: That's like a bad version of Simon's answer

Comment: @Raphael If you're going to answer a question, you need to explain fully. For example, what is `collection` here? How would you set it up?  What does your code do that the original one doesn't? Does it have any problems?

Comment: @DavidG I’m new here, tks for your feedback. 